# How do I pass the selected dropdown value to a controller in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How to transfer the selected value of the drop-down list (Thymeleaf) to the controller (Spring)? The list itself is formed normally, the problem is in the button.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="courier/notInTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteUser (@RequestParam String task) {
    System.out.println(task);
    return "redirect:/courier";
}
```

View:

```
<div class="taskList" th:object="${task}">
    <select class="form-control" id="courierTasks" name="courierTasks">
        <option value="">Select task for disable</option>
        <option th:each="task : ${tasks}"
                th:value="${task}"
                th:text="${task}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <form th:action="@{/courier/notInTime}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden"/>
        <button type="submit">Not in time</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sopheak @Ioannis many thx.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="courier/notInTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteUser (@Valid String task) {
    System.out.println(task);
    return "redirect:/courier";
}
```

View:

```
 <form th:action="@{/courier/notInTime}" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" id="task" name="task">
            <option value="">Select task for disable</option>
            <option th:each="task : ${tasks}"
                    th:value="${task}"
                    th:text="${task}">
            </option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Not in time</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the select tag inside the form, so the form submits the `task`.

Try the following

```
<form th:action="@{/courier/notInTime}" method="post">
  <div class="taskList" th:object="${task}">
    <select class="form-control" id="courierTasks" name="courierTasks">
        <option value="">Select task for disable</option>
        <option th:each="task : ${tasks}"
                th:value="${task}"
                th:text="${task}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden"/>
    <button type="submit">Not in time</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Note that you can write a simple javascript function so the form submits the `task` even if its outside the form, however, I cannot see the reason not to add the select in the form at your case.

Answer (score 1):

You just change @RequestParam to @Valid in your controller then change your select name to "task" in Thymeleaf and it should be into the form wrapper.

```
@RequestMapping(value="courier/notInTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteUser (@Valid String task) {
    System.out.println(task);
    return "redirect:/courier";
}

<select class="form-control" id="courierTasks" name="task">
    <option value="">Select task for disable</option>
    <option th:each="task : ${tasks}"
            th:value="${task}"
            th:text="${task}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: what about button?